# What is a good way of carrying out test train split with only 4 samples, and a large number of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, train-test-split

I have a dataset comprising of four samples, ~25,000 features, and two labels (it is a gene count dataset). What is a good way of splitting the data? When I run my model I am getting an accuracy of `1` on the training set, but `0` on the validation set.

Is bootstrapping worth trying out?

```
Labels = [0,1,0,1]

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data,labels,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)
```

Any thoughts of advice?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to avoid overfit in this dataset. You have way too few examples to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you cannot possibly hope to train a model with just four samples (and if you were to split, even less).

While assessing the needed number of samples a priori is not trivial and depends on many factors, a major one being data quality, the rules of thumb I have read in the past were along the lines of

- 1,000 samples per class
- at least 10 times the number of features

While these are most certainly oversimplifications, I guess with 4 samples or less, you are most certainly out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider reducing the dimensionality of your dataset to avoid overfitting with such a large number of features. You can use any method of feature selection, including filter-wrapper-embedded methods.

feature selection will
1- Improve model generalization and avoid overfitting.
2- Avoid dimension explosions.
3- Reduce training time.

Regarding bootstrapping, it's a helpful method for determining a model's performance. It is not, however, a solution for overfitting.

this can help very little with your problem. , **you need more data**

Comment: I have tried implementing feature selection using several algorithms, such as RFE with XGB, Gradient Boost Classifier, and extra trees classifier, however I am getting accuracy o 1 on training set, and 0 on validation set. I have tried adjusting parameters, but it feels like I am getting no where

Comment: @zmitchell244  you will need to increase your dataset , try some data agumentation and reguralization technqiues. if it still doesn't work . you will need to increase your dataset.